# Error defining AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am starting with AngularJS, creating my first App & Controller I get this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/ng/areq?p0=SheetController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

This is my portion of html code:

```
<div ng-app="SheetFrom">
    <div id="sheetform-container" ng-controller="SheetController">
        <form action="#">
        </form>     
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS file:

```
var ngApp;

ngApp = angular.module('SheetFrom', []);

ngApp.controller('SheetController', function() {

});
```

Any help please? Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you included your controller file in the html page ?

Comment: [This exact code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/1LLdorwo/)

Comment: Controller file? No, I will add all the html code inside the <form> tag...

Comment: html inside the form doesn't matter.  You need to make sure your js file is being included on the page load either by adding a script tag referencing the file to the page or by adding it to your base layout file if you're using one of those

Comment: Yes, it is included just right after include the angular.min.js file...

Comment: Are you sure that the JS file is being included?

Comment: `ng-view` is not a requirement to make Angular work, `ng-view` works in combination with `ngRoute` you don't necessarily have to have a routed application in order to have an Angular application.

Comment: Make sure everything is spelled correctly from inside your HTML to your app and controller definitions, it seems that its not finding the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I started with AngularJS. I solved it including

```
<script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure to set your app and controller in the right way, It may be giving you that error also for that reason. Write something like:

Html:

```
<div ng-app="fizzBuzzApp"></div>
```

App.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('fizzBuzzApp', []);
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('fizzBuzzController', function($scope){
});
```